# bootloader reading drive parameters

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, real-mode

I want to get dimensions of hard drive. I find that I need to use int 13h with ah = 08h. I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D08h:_Read_Drive_Parameters) that it returns following:

DH  logical last index of heads = number_of - 1 (because index starts with 0)

CX  [7:6] [15:8] logical last index of cylinders = number_of - 1 (because index starts with 0)

[5:0] logical last index of sectors per track = number_of (because index starts with 1)

The problem is that I have no idea how to read only bits [5:0] on it own to get last index of sector per track, and the same with [7:6][15:8] to get last index of cylinders. I would be really thankful if someone would point me into the right way or explain how to do this.

Comment: I dont have any code because I started from beginning, and Im thinking of develop some sort of file system. The thing that I need to do is to count how much 512 bit sectors is in this drive

Comment: I think that its pointless as long as I don't have idea what I'm doing

Comment: the code for that is not really hard it is just 5 maybe 6 lines of code
`xor ax,ax mov es,ax mov di,ax mov ah,0x08 int 13h` and `dl` that is drive number is set to right drive number by BIOS when reading bootloader

Comment: Do you a problem with extracting the partial values from the CX register?

Comment: @up yes that what is my problem

Comment: Most hard drives are larger than the "int 0x13, ah=0x08" BIOS function can describe. There's a newer set of functions ("int 0x13 extensions") that mostly exist to work around this limit (including an "int 0x13, ah=0x48" BIOS function that tells you the disk's parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov  ax, cx
and  ax, 63
shr  cl, 6
xchg cl, ch
```

This leaves sectors in AX and cylinders in CX